# List Categories on a CMS Page A-Z Style

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, category-tree

I am looking to achieve a brands listing page, listing brands (held as categories) alphabetically with a sub-group for each letter. For example, Adidas, Asics etc. would all appear under 'A', Barbour, Banks under 'B' and so on.

Here's my current code that does a great job of listing all the brand categories - however I am stuck trying to get them listed under the associated letter of the alphabet.

```
<?php
$parentCategoryId = 5;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId );
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$children->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $category->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//get only active categories if you want
    ->addAttributeToSort('name');//sort by position
 $mode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('mode');
?>

<div class="brands">
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($children as $child) {
        $skin_url = $child->getImageUrl(); ?>
        <li <?php if ($mode=='1'){echo 'style="width:100%"';}?>>
            <a href="<?php echo $child->getURL();?>" title="<?php echo $child->getName();?>">
                <span class="brand-name"><?php echo $child->getName();?></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php   }?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used below code on Magento 1.9 and it's working fine.

```
<?php 
$parentCategoryId = 31;//put your parent cat id here
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId );
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$children->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $category->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addAttributeToSort('name');                    

//perform some "lazy" grouping
$alph = array();
foreach ($children as $c) {
    $letter = strtolower(substr($c->getName(), 0, 1));
    $alph[$letter][] = $c;
}
?>

<div class="brands">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($alph as $letter => $children): ?>
        <li>
        <?php echo $letter; ?>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($children as $child){
                $skin_url = $child->getImageUrl(); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $child->getURL();?>" title="<?php echo $child->getName();?>">
                        <span class="brand-name"><?php echo $child->getName();?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <?php   }?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Works a charm. Thank you, sorry for late reply!